# Freeradius Unlang Checks against user file

Tags: freeradius

I'm trying to set up a freeradius server and I want to check if a user file has a certain attribute, how would I go about doing this.

I tried the following statement but it doesn't seem to have the desired effect of rejecting a user.

if ("%{wifi_key}" != 'true' {
    reject
}

thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a check item, it needs to be:

```
if (control:wifi_key != true) {
    reject
}
```